# Is there some offcial Active Record error translation in spanish?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

I have this exception:

```
translation missing: es.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
```

As far as I understand: it is raised because I don't have the spanish translations for active record. Are there official translations files for active record?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at the [rails-i18n repository](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) from Sven Fuchs. Just add it to your app. You can find the general spanish translations [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml).

Answer (score 0):

you just have to translate this file in your locale files:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml